# Wingdings Mouse Character in Start Menu

Tags: windows, fonts, windows-vista

A colleague here at work recently brought me their laptop because they were having troubles logging into their local machine account. I was able to repair that problem, but noticed that a little mouse icon was being displayed to the right of the "Recent Items" menu item on the Start Menu. This is happening on all the accounts on the machine. I've identified the character's source as the font Wingdings, but I am baffled as to why it is being displayed instead of the traditional right-pointing arrow. Here is a screen shot of what I am talking about.

[image: Recent Items with a mouse icon instead of arrow to the right.]

OS is Windows Vista Home Premium.

Comment: I found this: http://www.vistaheads.com/forums/windows-vista-blogs-forum/59197-fixing-arrow-recent-items-read.html It says something about an XML file, but I couldn't figure out where an xml file would be hiding for it. Good luck!

Comment: @Duall: That URL stole content from http://web.archive.org/web/20070621165558/http://www.windowsxlive.net/?p=942 .

Comment: I apologize, I just googled it and that seemed to be the only thing available. =(

Comment: It wants you to click on it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Font cache corruption maybe?

From http://word.mvps.org/faqs/apperrors/commonfontprobs.htm and http://forum.piriform.com/index.php?showtopic=4581

Consider wiping out the font cache; delete these files if they exist and reboot

```
    C:\Windows\System32\FNTCACHE.DAT
    C:\Windows\ttfCache
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Windows Vista still uses the marlett.ttf font for those things and somehow you don't have it in the fonts folder?

Answer (score -1):

Could this be a corrupted installation of [Vista Transformation Pack](http://www.windowsxlive.net/vista-transformation-pack) ?  If so, just reinstall VTP.